# Обстоятельство места и правильность стилистики

Tags: стилистика, синтаксис

Добрый день.
Возник вопрос касательно синтаксического разбора предложения ("Чудесная аллея из тополей стояла на дороге".)
1 вопрос. "На дороге" — является обстоятельством места или дополнением?
2 вопрос. Верно ли стилистически писать о том, что аллея стояла на дороге? Ведь аллея и есть дорога.
С уважением, Николай Шамин.

Answer (score 1):

На дороге - обстоятельство места. Аллея  стоять не может. Нигде. ЧТо же у Вас там в контексте?  А то не знаешь. как и поправить... Может, вдоль дороги росли чудесные тополя?